# How do I run Python Docker containers in the background and use them in my commands?

Tags: python, docker

I want to use different Python versions in my tests. I want to have 3 Docker containers for Python 3.6, Python 3.7 and Python 3.8 running and I want the commands `python3.6`, `python3.7`, `python3.8` to be accessible in the environment.

If it can also associate these containers with just `python` command, that could help as well.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried `docker pull` and `docker run` :) Then I got stuck. Another thing is that I couldn't keep it running in the background as it just exited.

Comment: [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a purpose-built, non-Docker tool for using multiple Python versions in tests.

Comment: Check logs why your container is not running. Are you running them with `-d` (in detached mode)? Also remember, that you will probably need to mount your volume to your container, so it can access your files. Then just create script (shell or bat, depending on your OS) in your path, which will be called e.g. `python3.6` and which will do e.g. `docker exec <your_container> python3 $1`.

Comment: @DavidMaze tox is also something I am using. But regardless of what I use, I still need to have other versions of Python somewhere in my system (I believe). In `docker:dind` environment only `3.8` is available through `apk` and that I can easily use. But I had problems with other versions, even with tox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you mean you want 3 docker containers running, each with a different Python version.
And you want to execute commands from the host for each python container.

You can do this with the following scripts:

### docker-compose.yml

Create a docker-compose.yml file with the following content:

```sh
version: '3.9'

services:

  python36:
    image: python:3.6.14-buster
    container_name: python36
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: ["sleep", "30d"]

  python37:
    image: python:3.7.11-buster
    container_name: python37
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: [ "sleep", "30d" ]


  python38:
    image: python:3.8.11-buster
    container_name: python38
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: [ "sleep", "30d" ]
```

### Python script to run

In a folder called ./app create a file called version.py

```py
import sys

print(sys.version)
```

### Command on the Host

Create a Bash script on the host running the version.py for all three containers.
Call it run_command.sh (and 'chmod 755' it of course)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

docker exec -it python36 python version.py
docker exec -it python37 python version.py
docker exec -it python38 python version.py
```

Run it with:

```sh
./run_command.sh
```

### output

The output:

```sh
$ ./run_command.sh
3.6.14 (default, Jun 29 2021, 21:23:13)
[GCC 8.3.0]
3.7.11 (default, Jun 29 2021, 20:31:06)
[GCC 8.3.0]
3.8.11 (default, Jun 29 2021, 19:54:56)
[GCC 8.3.0]
```